# How to find files accessible on external network?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners

It was recently brought to my attention that there was a zip file containing a database backup accessible on my external network.

Is there a tool that will scan my external ips and return files that are accessible?

Answer (score 1):

You could try with ENT (Essential NetTools) or a similar Utility to do a shared-resource scan from outside your Network and see what it finds.